# How to access a local file located in a folder with a reserved system name on Windows like "CON"?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, path, filesystems

I need to access a file that is located under a local path that contains a folder that is named `con`. Folder names like `con`, `nul`, etc are reserved for use in specific system tasks and trying to access a file under such directories will result in the following messages:

- Form the command prompt: "The system cannot find the path specified."
- From file explorer: "C:\Users\USERNAME\con is not accessible". The handle is invalid.

If I cannot change the name of such folders, how can I access such files?

I note that such folder names can be created in the command prompt with the following command:

```
md con\
```

and can be removed with:

```
rd /q /s con
```

Furthermore, files can be successfully added by dragging them into the folder using explorer.

I have also tried using git-bash to create, delete, and open the content of such directories and everything seem to work just fine however, when I try from windows, files are not accessible even if they are clearly in the path.

Comment: Answer: don't use reserved names.

Comment: Since most commands do not allow such reserved names for normal files/directories, I consider this a design flaw of the `md` and `rd` commands. Therefore although TheIncorrigible1's reply is not satisfactory, they are right...

Comment: @aschipfl the point of asking this question was to see if anyone else knew of a way to tackle this issue. Unfortunately I am constrained by a number of factors. I appreciate that this issue is non-trivial.

Comment: You already have a resolution: use linux tools.

Comment: Copy what you need from the "CON" directories and delete them. Put the files into directories without "CON" in the path. If someone else is creating "CON" directories, please let them know how lacking in common sense this is.

Comment: There's nothing reserved about "CON" at the kernel or file-system driver level. This is just a DOS compatibility hack in the ntdll runtime library functions that normalize and convert legacy DOS paths to native NT paths such as `RtlGetFullPathName_U` and `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U`. This behavior can be bypassed by using a fully-qualified path prefixed by "\\?\". However, it's not working right in PowerShell, in which I can create but cannot remove "\\?\C:\Temp\con". Unfortunately .NET and shell functions often reinvent the wheel **badly**.

Comment: @eryksun I don't quite understand what you are suggesting to do

Comment: Note that for me (Windows 10) it is not possible to use `md` or `rd` without the `\\?\\` trick.

Comment: Apparently you need to add `-literalpath` to make `rd` (i.e. `remove-item`) work correctly with "\\?\" paths. It's annoying to require this redundant option when nothing should be more literal than a "\\?\" path already is.

Comment: @eryksun I was more referring to what the OP said that `md` and `rd` worked for him out of the box (without "\\?\") on the command prompt (`cmd`, not powershell), but I couldn't replicate that.

Comment: @letmaik, adding a trailing backslash works and isn't related to CMD per se. It's particular to creating and accessing a directory. NT's RTL normalizes a DOS device that's in the final path component. By including the trailing backslash, "con" is not the final component. This won't help with creating a regular file named "con", however.

Comment: Or "con.txt", "con  .txt", and other variations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix it with `\\?\` as described [here](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2016/05/09/invalid-file-handle-when-trying-to-delete-a-file/), that should work fine in PowerShell as shown in this [example](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2018/01/16/remove-windows-old-folder/).

```
PS C:\temp\posh> gci
PS C:\temp\posh> cmd /c "md con\"
PS C:\temp\posh> gci


    Directory: C:\temp\posh


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         12-06-18     09:24                con


PS C:\temp\posh> rm -LiteralPath '\\?\c:\temp\posh\con\'
PS C:\temp\posh> gci
PS C:\temp\posh>
```

And here's how to write and read a file inside a folder with a reserved name with PowerShell:

```
PS C:\temp\posh> "test" | out-file -LiteralPath "\\?\c:\temp\posh\con\test.txt"
PS C:\temp\posh> Get-Content -LiteralPath "\\?\c:\temp\posh\con\test.txt"
test
PS C:\temp\posh>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. `cd : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is not valid. Change the value of the "path"
argument and run the operation again.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd \\?\con
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand`

Comment: Also, using PowerShell would not solve the issue of having an executable reading a file under the `con` folder.

Comment: Added example but as mentioned in the comments by someone else you really shouldn't used reserved names.

Comment: thank you for the info however I think that my question was misunderstood. In my port I had already shown that I am able to create and remove the folder named `con` using the command prompt. What you are showing here is how to do it in Powershell.What I was trying to get at was to open a file in such folder for example in c:\mypath\con/myfile.txt

Comment: In the same way @Kievit see the extra example I've added

Comment: @Kievit, no extra syntax is required to open "c:\mypath\con\myfile.txt". The DOS device name is not the final path component.

Comment: @Remko. Thank you. I would also like to note that the same method can be used in the command prompt. For example to edit a file one could do: `notepad \\?\C:\mypath\con\myfile.txt`.

Comment: @Kievit, using the "\\?\" prefix to access "C:\mypath\con\myfile.txt" doesn't hurt, but you don't fully comprehend the DOS compatibility rules if you think it's required. Again, in this case "con" is not in the leaf component of the path, so the RTL *does not* reparse the path as "\\.\con".

Comment: is it possible to open that `con` folder without command i mean what if there is file `example.mp4` `pic.jpg` in it how can we view and play these files

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

Warning: I have not tried this method before. Be sure to back up your files before starting.

1. Download and install 'Run as System tool' by clicking [here](https://apreltech.com/Downloads/runassystem.exe)

2. Run the application and type in 'cmd.exe'
3. When you see a command prompt window, type in cd C:\con
4. If it let's you access the folder, type in 'dir' to see the files inside con

---

If you are curious about why I wrote these steps, look below.

I think this method WILL work because the SYSTEM account might have access to con, so seeing the contents of con might work with running cmd as SYSTEM user

---

Enjoy

Johnson Saji